# Power shell script to produce Azure Data Factory name of trigger list, schedule time and frequency

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory

Please help me to write a powershell script to get list of azure data factory triggers list and its scheduling time. Ex: TriggerName,Frequency,ScheduleTime
Tr_Copy_Data,Daily,13:30

Thank you in advance.

Get list of azure data factory triggers and it’s schedule time for

Comment: What is your approach? what error you facing?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You have to post your attempt before asking here

Answer (score 1):

Run this below script in your azure powershell.

```
$resourceGroupName = "Your_resource_group"
$dataFactoryName = "Your_data_factory_name"

$triggers = Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $dataFactoryName

$triggerInfo = @()

foreach ($trigger in $triggers) {
    $triggerName = $trigger.Name
    $frequency = $triggers.Properties.Recurrence.Frequency
    $Interval = $trigger.Properties.Recurrence.Interval
    $Hours = $triggers.Properties.Recurrence.Schedule.Hours
    $Minutes = $triggers.Properties.Recurrence.Schedule.Minutes

    # Add the information to the array
    $triggerInfo += [PSCustomObject]@{
        TriggerName = $triggerName
        Frequency = $frequency
        Interval = $Interval
    Hours = $Hours
    Minutes = $Minutes
    }
}

$triggerInfo | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Below is the trigger scheduled every day at 10:30.

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I will test your suggestion. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST API :
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/12345678-1234-1234-1234-12345678abc/resourceGroups/exampleResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/exampleFactoryName/triggers?api-version=2018-06-01

to get the trigger details

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/triggers/list-by-factory?tabs=HTTP